# "duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzfkt.class"

Tags: react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to build a React Native project on Android, but I'm running into all sorts of Android dependency issues. Currently, I'm seeing this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzfkt.class
```

Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native-background-geolocation-android/android/libs"
        }
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native-background-fetch/android/libs"
        }
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion   = 26
    targetSdkVersion    = 26
    buildToolsVersion   = "26.0.2"
    supportLibVersion   = "26.1.0"
    playServicesVersion = "11.8.0"
}
```

And my `app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
        applicationId "com.gonote"
        minSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1' //this decides your firebase SDK version
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile project(':react-native-svg')
    compile project(':react-native-sms')
    compile project(':react-native-image-resizer')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-fcm')
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile project(':react-native-contacts')
    compile project(':react-native-background-geolocation-android')
    compile project(':react-native-background-fetch')
    compile project(':react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box')
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile project(':react-native-contacts')
    compile project(':react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box')
    compile project(':react-native-background-fetch')
    compile project(':react-native-background-fetch')
    compile project(':react-native-background-geolocation-android')
    compile project(':react-native-background-geolocation-android')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibVersion"
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

This error message gives me very little to go on. From what I've found searching google is it's caused by some kind of google play services version mismatch, but I have no idea how I'm supposed to find it in this mess.

Comment: This is when building for `release` right?

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/343) or [this](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation/issues/351)

Comment: @Chisko I came across both of those in my search for a solution. Neither of them clearly explains what needs to change. I understand I have "two versions of the Google libraries being imported", but I don't see where this is happening.

Comment: There is one that suggests to update `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1` to 11.2 or 12.0 or something. Read carefully

Answer (score 0):

This bug is related to different versions of gms module required by different libraries that you use in the project. Please check this article for the best explanation on how to fix it: https://medium.com/@suchydan/how-to-solve-google-play-services-version-collision-in-gradle-dependencies-ef086ae5c75f

Comment: I added `exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'` to `react-native-fcm` and `react-native-device-info`, and now I'm seeing this error: `Could not find method exclude() for arguments [{group=com.google.android.gms}] on project ':react-native-fcm' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`